# CodeIgniter WebService Restful

Tags: web-services, rest, codeigniter-2

I need an axample to use CodeIgniter restful because this class can't work:

class Books extends REST_Controller
{
   .....
}
I need to create a single point of access to both the login and for the register so that the register in a system the user has access to all the others, then I will have only one database to store and query data from users. My question is: What is the best option when it comes to Webservice, SOAP or REST? I read that SOAP is heavier and slower, however also read that REST has fewer features. What do you suggest me? Login via Webservice safe?